# Microphone stopped working 1809 only (no updates installed)

Tags: windows, drivers, microphone, audio-recording

Son has a Plantronics HD1 headset with microphone.
Yesterday microphone worked. 
Today it didn't.
Windows 10 1809. No patches installed since 26th December.

All PCs here have all privacy options "Let apps access [device]" set to deny.
(And Windows states this only blocks apps from accessing the device, not Windows - and by extension Win32 programs).

On my 1709 PC with "Let apps access my microphone" set to Deny it works fine.

On 1809 I had to temporarily "allow users to control" for this permission, then turn it on in privacy options and the microphone works. This should be a temporary solution only - as he was pestering me to get it working.

*EDIT: The headset is connected via USB. We tried all four front ports and a couple of rear ports*

But I want to isolate the real cause of the problem because I will not be enabling any of the privacy options on any PC in my home.

I've been through all the troubleshooters, and checked all settings, uninstalled and reinstalled the device, rebooted, and so on... Nothing solved the problem.

So, guru's, I'd value your thoughts on what might have resulted in it suddenly ceasing to work, when nothing had been changed on the PC between yesterday and today.

thanks.

Comment: Is it a USB, audiojack or bluetooth connected headset?

Comment: Post updated with headset type.

Comment: Its a guess, but given that it is a USB device and can be unplugged, it is possible, the moment you unplug the device, windows changes the recording device to the onboard soundcard, and somehow doesn't set the recording device back to the headset. Can you verify that the headset works in the windows settings, and that it is set as recording device there?

Comment: @LPChip normally the headphones are left plugged in and the user selects the desired device in settings. However, I've been testing and Windows is detecting the headphones as soon as he plugs them in, and reverts to "Stereo Mix" (the only other input source), when he unplugs. We can get the microphone working by disabling privacy settings (Which are not supposed to affect desktop apps). In Windows settings we can see the level indicator respond to voice when the privacy setting is disabled.

Comment: It sounds like this is by design then. A bad design... But that is Microsoft anyway. Also it could be a bug. I don't think you can fix this other than disabling the privacy settings or reverting back to 1803.

Comment: If I hadn't seen him using the headphones/microphone with the privacy settings disabled, I'd probably agree. The privacy settings are supposed to only apply to the UWP (or whatever they are calling them now), apps, not Windows settings and Win32/desktop apps. So I know it definitely worked with the privacy settings set to deny. I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place. He wants a microphone, I want all telemetry and privacy related settings disabled. He was on 1709... I haven't tested 1803. 1709 support runs out soon I'll install 1803 on my test PC and see if the problem is the same there.

Comment: I knew I'd read it somewhere... https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10-camera-and-privacy - "Desktop apps won’t appear in your Choose which apps can access your camera or Choose which apps can access your microphone lists and are not affected by the Allow apps to access your camera or Allow apps to access your microphone setting. To allow or block desktop apps, use the settings in those applications."